# How would I split a list of many rows by sections using loops

Tags: python-3.x

If a_list is a list of many rows of integers, where suppose to print a split version of that list into three parts first row plus the two following, the middle row plus the row before and after and the last row plus the two rows before it using three loops.

```
Print entire list a_list if its length is less than or equal to
3 times section_size (an int).

Otherwise, print the first
section_size elements of a_list, followed by an ellipsis ("...")

followed by the middle section_size elements, followed by another
ellipsis, followed by the final section_size elements.

Note: This function assumes its parameters' values are valid, and
does no exception handling.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def contract(lst, size=3):
    if len(lst) <= size * 3:
        return lst

    mid = (len(lst) - 1) // 2
    mid_size = (size - 1) // 2

    new_lst = lst[:size]
    new_lst += ["..."] + lst[mid-mid_size:mid+mid_size+1]
    new_lst += ["..."] + lst[-size:]

    return new_lst

lst = [[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [10, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [13, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
 [14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]]

for row in contract(lst, 3):
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
...
[6, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[7, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[8, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
...
[12, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[13, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[14, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```